# Point cloud library not working on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, point-cloud-library, boost-interprocess, vcpkg

I've installed the pointcloud library with vcpkg. I used the command line "vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows" and had all the other libraries installed along with PCL. After that I used ".\vcpkg\vcpkg integrate install" to have all the libraries working directly in my Visual Studio 2019 project. In fact, my project (containing the sample demo code at https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/writing_pcd.html#writing-pcd ) after the command had included correctly the two header files and was showing no issues.
After running the code however I got a bunch of errors related to the boost library such as:

```
Error   C2116   'boost::interprocess::winapi::GetFileSizeEx': function parameter lists do not match between declarations    RegistrationAlgorithm   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\fileapi.h    

Error   C2733   'CreateSemaphoreA': you cannot overload a function with 'C' linkage RegistrationAlgorithm   C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\interprocess\detail\win32_api.hpp

Error   C4996   '_open': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _sopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.    RegistrationAlgorithm   C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\pcl\io\low_level_io.h
```

Same exact question (same example code, same errors) was asked here: [point cloud library not working in VS 2019 but does work in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510012/point-cloud-library-not-working-in-vs-2019-but-does-work-in-vs-2017/63263797?noredirect=1#comment111869841_63263797)

However, he managed to have it working by switching to Visual Studio 2017 Build tools (v141) from VS2019 Build tools (v142). I downloaded v141 and switched but I am still getting the same errors.

Any advice?

I tried having the code run through CMake but through that process I encounter many more errors.

Comment: ***Any advice?*** You may want to post a bug report on the vcpkg github page

Answer (score 2):

It's a compatibility problem between boost interprocess and MSVC 2019.
According to [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/756694/including-windowsh-and-boostinterprocess-headers-l.html) you can use a [not-yet-documented](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/1594) compatibility switch in MSVC 2019 to prevent the `C2116` and `C2733` errors relating to redeclaration of extern "C" functions.  This option is `/Zc:externC-`

This leaves a couple of `C4996` errors relating to use of insecure CRT functions.
Per the error message, these can be suppressed by writing `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before the header files are included.

With both these, the sample code builds here fine.

---

Edit: to add that option follow this menu/dialog route -

- Project / Properties / C/C++ / Command Line, then type that option into the Additional Options text box at the bottom

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I managed to remove the C4996 error thanks to you, but being a newbie with Visual Studio I don't know how to "activate" that switch. Could you please elaborate some more?

Comment: Thank you so much. After two days of struggling the solution seems close. I just noticed there was one more error, which is the only one left, which is:


`Error C3861 'pop_t': identifier not found RegistrationAlgorithm C:\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\flann\algorithms\dist.h`

If you happen to know how to fix this too, that'd be great. thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that error here.  I appears to be related to the flann package not boost interprocess so it's a different issue. Perhaps ask a new question ?

Comment: Hopefully the /Zc:externC- workaround will not be needed in future Boost versions (starting in soon to be released Boost 1.74). The related Boost.Interprocess bug report is [Issue 99](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/issues/99)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions to C3861:

You could move the "typedef unsigned long long pop_t;" outside the #if and #else so that either one will use the parameter to do the math. If `FLANN` is installed in either Program Files or Program Files (x86), you'll need to run Visual Studio as an Administrator. Program Files and Program Files (x86) are protected and need elevated permissions to edit any of the directories' contents.
[image]

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/issues/386) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working. Had to move the line outside the #if and #else in my case.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to mark both answers as answers.

Comment: I would appreciate it If you could choose a suitable answer to mark, because it could helps others.

Comment: I understand, what I meant is that I cannot mark neither of the two, because it tells me I have not enough reputation points to mark the answer. Other people will have to vote as well and after a threshold it will be marked, otherwise I would have done it for sure.